# STS is Publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, publishing-site

I want to ask a very simple question.

- Is STS a publishing site ?
- Is BDR#0 a Publishing site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BDR#0 is the Document Center site template. Per this page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2007/05/06/creating-document-center-sites-on-a-publishing-portal.aspx

...there is a bit of a bug which requires you to provision both the Standard and Enterprise features to make the site show up. I believe that it is *not* a Publishing site; however, it can be used with Publishing.